# Python json : parse and update file json not work

Tags: json, python-3.x, parsing

i was unsuccessful in parsing and updating data in json, this is my json structure :

```
[{"name":"budi",
  "data siswa":
    {
      "nik":125872018331,
      "tanggal lahir":10111990

      }
      }]
```

My code :

```
import json

update_nik = '2234567'
with open('myfile.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)  
  f.close()

read_nik = data["data siswa"]["nik"]
print (read_nik)

update_nik = data["data siswa"]["nik"] = update_nik
print(update_nik)
```

any help that I really appreciate.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON structure correct you have a list which contains dict.
You need to get "data siswa" like this data[0]["data siswa"]

Your code will be like this if you need to update "nik" field

```
import json

update_nik = '2234567'
with open('myfile.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)  
  f.close()

  read_nik = data[0]["data siswa"]["nik"]
  print (read_nik)

  update_nik = data[0]["data siswa"]["nik"] = update_nik
  print(update_nik)
```